# Using sinatra checkboxes to filter searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, sinatra

search.rb

```
keywords = ["sheffield", "liverpool", "london", "manchester"]

get '/search' do

  @keyword = "No keyword entered"
  @results = []
  puts keywords[0]

  unless params[:filter].nil?
      @tick_box1 = params[:filter][:follower] == 'on'
      @tick_box2 = params[:filter][:following] == 'on'
  end

  if (@tick_box1) && (@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('chelsea').take(20)
  elsif (@tick_box1) && (!@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('arsenal').take(20)
  elsif (!@tick_box1) && (@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('liverpool').take(20)
  else
    unless params[:keyword].nil?
      @keyword = params[:keyword]
      @results = @client.search(@keyword).take(20)
    end

    unless params[:use_keyword].nil?
      @results = @client.search(keywords[0]).take(20)
    end
  end
    erb :search
end
```

Search.erb

```
<% query = "" %>
<h1>Search</h1>

<div class="search-container">
    <form>
        <input type="search" name="keyword" value="<%=h params[:query]%>">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
        <a href="?use_keyword=1" class="button">Use Keywords</a>
        <a href="settings">Edit Keywords</a>

        <div class="filters">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[follower]">Followers</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[folowing]">Following</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>


    <% if query != "" %>
    <p>Showing results for <strong><%=h query %></strong></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= @keyword %>
    <ol class="search-results">
        <% @results.each do |result| %>
        <li><%= result.text %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
    <%= erb :"partials/pagination", :locals => {
        :total_results => 100,
        :results_per_page => 10,
        :current_page => 1
    }%>
```

I want to make it so when check boxes are selected it searches the certain category (eg followers following). But at the moment even if i check the tick boxes it still searches the entered keyword. But i only want it to search the whole of twitter for the entered keyword if i don't select any of the check boxes. Does anyone have any solutions.

ps( i will write the code for searching followers and following later when I've figured this out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your view, you have the checkboxes in another form so when you hit Search, they are not sent. You need all of the inputs in one form.

Comment: I've updated it now and added random search terms but at the moment it only works for 'arsenal' which should is just followers ticked. When both are ticked it also searches  'arsenal' instead of 'chelsea' and when just following is ticked it searches the inputted keyword instead of 'liverpool'. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong now?

Answer (score 0):

search.rb

```
 keywords = ["sheffield", "liverpool", "london", "manchester"]

get '/search' do

  @keyword = "No keyword entered"
  @results = []
  puts keywords[0]

  unless params[:filter].nil?
      @tick_box1 = params[:filter][:follower] == 'on'
      @tick_box2 = params[:filter][:following] == 'on'
  end

  if (@tick_box1) && (@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('chelsea').take(20)
  elsif (@tick_box1) && (!@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('arsenal').take(20)
  elsif (!@tick_box1) && (@tick_box2)
    @results = @client.search('liverpool').take(20)
  else
    unless params[:keyword].nil?
      @keyword = params[:keyword]
      @results = @client.search(@keyword).take(20)
    end

    unless params[:use_keyword].nil?
      @results = @client.search(keywords[0]).take(20)
    end
  end
    erb :search
end

<% query = "" %>
<h1>Search</h1>
```

search.erb

```
<div class="search-container">
    <form>
        <input type="search" name="keyword" value="<%=h params[:query]%>">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
        <a href="?use_keyword=1" class="button">Use Keywords</a>
        <a href="settings">Edit Keywords</a>

        <div class="filters">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[follower]">Followers</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="filter[following]">Following</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>


    <% if query != "" %>
    <p>Showing results for <strong><%=h query %></strong></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= @keyword %>
    <ol class="search-results">
        <% @results.each do |result| %>
        <li><%= result.text %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ol>
    <%= erb :"partials/pagination", :locals => {
        :total_results => 100,
        :results_per_page => 10,
        :current_page => 1
    }%>
```